# How to Set Color Key on wayland

Tags: wayland

There was a interface (called setColorKey) to control the framebuffer, making a specific color to be transparent. Is there a similar thing in wayland client ?

Comment: What library do you use ? How do you create your buffers ?

Answer (score 1):

Transparency must be handled by the client, depending on the used pixel format.

So, the behavior you're asking for depends on your buffer generation.